# addin to enhance VB6 undo-redo fuctionality

Tags: vb6, undo-redo

The VB6 IDE has a very basic undo and redo mechanism, stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440706(office.12).aspx#CommunityContent)

I want it to undo changes like if I move a button to some plave and press Ctrl+Z it should move back to its previous position.

Can anyone guide me to a VB6 addin that does this?

Comment: The link you provided is about the VBA editor in Office 2000, not the VB6 IDE. But it's true enough, the VB6 IDE can't undo some mouse operations in the form design window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such add-in as far as I know. The best solution is to use a version control system like [subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), so that you can track your changes and undo them at any future time if you wish.

I think I [advised you to use version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396417/changes-to-a-dialog-wont-appear-when-i-run-it-in-visual-basic-using-vb-editor-6-0/3396456#3396456) in a comment on your other question where you said you'd inherited a huge VB6 application?

Comment: for some reason i cant spot any subversion in my question you refered.

Comment: I didn't mention *subversion* but I did say [I hope you are using version control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396417/changes-to-a-dialog-wont-appear-when-i-run-it-in-visual-basic-using-vb-editor-6-0/3396456#3396456)

Comment: Too bad that it cannot do this. Better yet, put your code in a automatic snapshot system so an fat finger moments can be easily checked without you having to be checking into source control all the time. What I do is automatically sync all my Windohs coding to a shared folder running on ZFS with regular (15min) snapshots.